# iTerm2 & Terminal Giving >> [33[01;32m]u@h[33[00m]:[33[01;36m]w[33[00m]$

Tags: macos, terminal.app, prompt, iterm2

I opened iTerm2 and it changed the prompt to..

> > [33[01;32m]u@h[33[00m]:[33[01;36m]w[33[00m]$

I have no idea how this happened, and I can't figure out how to change it. I went to terminal to see if I had the same problem, and it shows the same prompt :/

I did a Google search and it brings up info about Vim, which I have never used, so I'm a little confused. Other people use my computer to help me though, so maybe someone switched something on accident. I'm using a MacBook running 10.8.4.

Comment: That output is controlled by your PS1 variable. It is trying to set the colors for your prompt. However it seems those aren't the right escape codes. Did you change your `$TERM` variable. (Probably should be xterm or xterm-256color) You should be able to change it in the menus for iterm2 (However I can't tell you which as I'm not sitting front of iterm2 right now)

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff for leading in me the right direction. This website guided me through the problem, which was a bash profile: http://mattmazur.com/2012/01/27/how-to-change-your-default-terminal-prompt-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 1):

If your prompt is broken, here are the files you should check for any statements containing `PS1`:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/profile`

At least on OS X, those are where you'd typically alter your interactive prompt. If only your prompt is broken, and not the entire shell, it should be easy to edit the files in a normal text editor, e.g.

```
open -e ~/.bash_profile
```

Remove any offending lines that set `PS1`, save the configuration file, and restart your shell.

Answer (score 0):

They are colour sequences and here is what I have in my .bash_profile

```
  BLACK='\e[0;30m'
  BLUE='\e0;34m'
  BROWN='\e[0;33m'
  CYAN='\e[0;36m'
  DARKGRAY='\e[1;30m'
  GRAY='\e[0;37m'
  GREEN='\e[32m'
  LIGHTBLUE='\e[1;34m'
  LIGHTCYAN='\e[1;36m'
  LIGHTGRAY='\e[0;37m'
  LIGHTGREEN='\e[1;32m'
  LIGHTPURPLE='\e[1;35m'
  LIGHTRED='\e[1;31m'
  PURPLE='\e[0;35'
  RED='\e[0;31m'
  YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
  NC='\e[m'

#  Variables PCT and PS1 can be merged into a new PS1 variable:
  PS1="\`if [[ \$EUID -eq 0 ]]; then PCT='\[$LIGHTRED\]';
  else PCT='\[$LIGHTCYAN\]'; fi;
  echo '\[$NC\]['\$PCT'\u\[$YELLOW\]@\[$GREEN\]\h:\w\[$NC\]]\[$GRAY\] : \[$NC\]'\`"
```